# DataTrigger setter will not update property. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML :

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonA">
        <RadioButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=RadioAValue}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxA, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </RadioButton.Style>
    </RadioButton>
```

C# Code behind

```
public bool RadioAValue
{
    get
    {
    ...
    }
    set
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

set section of `RadioAvalue` will not be called when `CheckBoxA` is checked.
Any reason why?

Comment: Actually there is no need of `Triggers` here.  You can directly bind `RadioAValue` to the `IsChecked` property of the `Checkbox`

Comment: I wanted conditional setter. If CheckBoxA is checked then only RadioButtonA should be checked. Not the otherway.

Comment: `<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonA" IsChecked={Binding RadioAValue}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Problem in your code**

You are setting the binding in `Style Setter`

```
<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=RadioAValue}" />
```

and on clicking the `checkbox` you have overwriting the `Binding` with the value `False`.  Now ***there is no more Bindings over the element*** and it wont call the set anymore.

Also, if you try to bind it over the `RadioButton` itself instead of `setters` that will take more precedence and your `Triggers` won't work there.

### **Solution**

I would recommend you to have `Command` binding over the `Checkbox` and update the value `RadioAValue` from your ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

If you want conditional setter use MultiBinding, right now you block binding with already setted value

```
<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=RadioAValue}" />
```

Must be something like this (didn't test thought):

```
<RadioButton x:Name="YouRadioButton">
        <RadioButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxA, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RadioAValue}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxA, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </RadioButton.Style>
    </RadioButton>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxA"/>
```